# Cocos2d-X android pugixml write xml file

Tags: android, c++, xml, cocos2d-x

How do you write to a xml file in Android using PugiXML?
Reading goes very well this way:

```
pugi::xml_document doc;

unsigned char* pBuffer = NULL;
unsigned long bufferSize = 0;
pBuffer = cocos2d::CCFileUtils::sharedFileUtils()->getFileData("leveldata.xml", "rb", &bufferSize);

pugi::xml_parse_result result = doc.load_buffer(pBuffer, bufferSize);
```

But what about writing?

Regards,
Gjjansen

Comment: http://pugixml.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/docs/manual/saving.html

Comment: Has anyone an idea? The last thing that i can do is to use fopen.
But i think that a lot of unnecessary work!

Comment: have you read the above comment?